# Stop SKAction at collision with PhysicsBody

Tags: ios, objective-c, sprite-kit, accelerometer, physics

I have a `SpriteNode` which is affected by gravity only on the y-Axis and can be moved with the accelerometer on the x-Axis. I also have a border (`SKPhysicsBody`) on my Scene which keeps my node inside my scene. The problem is now that my node ignores the border when it performs its `SKAction` caused by the accelerometer.

My code for the x movement/ accelerometer and its action:

`birdNode` is my `SpriteNode`

```
float destX = 0.0;


         float currentX = birdNode.position.x;
         BOOL shouldMove = NO;

         if (data.acceleration.x < -0.1) {
             destX = currentX + (data.acceleration.x * playerXSpeed);
             shouldMove = YES;
         }
         else if (data.acceleration.x > 0.1) {
             destX = currentX + (data.acceleration.x * playerXSpeed);
             shouldMove = YES;
         }

         if (shouldMove) {
             if (birdNode.position.x + destX < self.frame.size.width || birdNode.position.x - destX > 0) {

                SKAction *moveBird = [SKAction moveToX:destX duration:0.1];
                 [birdNode runAction:moveBird];
             }
         }
```

Comment: What do the variables "data.acceleration.x" and "playerXSpeed" represent?

Comment: data.acceleration.x is the value from the accelerometer and playerXSpeed sets the speed, it is set to 80

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that you have your collision bit masks properly set up to handle collisions. You should confirm this with a test to double check.

I believe your issue is with the speed of your object. If the object is moving too fast, and I do not see any velocity limits in your posted code, your object can move past the screen boundary in one update cycle.

For example, your current object's position is (400,100). Given enough velocity, your object's next update: position could be (600,100). This means that your object literally jumped past the boundary without causing a collision.

The solution is to either limit the velocity or to institute a position check before setting your object's new position. For example, if the new x position is > the screen width then set the x position to the max allowed screen width x.

Comment: No, this is not the problem. The action has nothing in common with physics - I think that this is the problem why my node is ignoring the border.
I have tried to do a check but it is still not working.. I have updated my code

Comment: @DavidP - Add the code NSLog(@"self: %@", NSStringFromCGPoint(yourObjectName.position)); into your update: method and see how big the x coordinate change is from frame to frame.

Comment: Not a wide range.. Between 140 and 280

Comment: That's within view range. What about the x position when your object jumps out of the view?

Comment: The node reaches up to -2000

Comment: What is log's x value which shows the x coordinate still within the view range and the immediately next log's x value?

Comment: When the node drops of it starts with 3 and jumps very fast to -190 in just 20 log's

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/51698/discussion-between-sangony-and-david-p)

Comment: Sorry, I am currently unavailable. I am back in 2 hours